# How could the text color inside the VSCode PDF preview be changed?

Tags: viewers, vscode, visual-studio-code

I want to make LaTeX Workshop's PDF preview fit my Visual Studio Code's theme, and I managed to change the background color of the previewed file following [this](http://fuzihaofzh.github.io/blog/2021/06/12/Changing-the-Background-Color-for-VSCode-PDF-Reviewer/) guide, however if I make the background a darker color, the black text becomes very hard to read, and I'd like to modify it to a lighter color, but I'm not sure how.